# What characteristics make The Faerie Queene an example of Renaissance literature?

Tags: history-of-literature, edmund-spenser, the-faerie-queene

Edmund Spenser's epic poem *The Faerie Queene* was published in the years 1590 (books I–III) and 1596 (books I–VI, i.e. complete).
It is primarily an allegorical work, and allegories were not new in the Renaissance: allegories can also be found in classical literature and medieval literature.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faerie_Queene#Theological_structure) mentions the work's theological structure, especially in book I. But I doubt that literature inspired by theology was new either.

Except for the date and publication, what characteristics make Spenser's *The Faerie Queene* an example of Renaissance literature?
Is there anything else than the relevance of theology mentioned in the Wikipedia article?

(Periodisation is challenging. Simply claiming that the work was written between year x and year y is insufficient, since that raises the question why those years are considered as constituting a specific literary period in the first place.)